# the probability that the system remains at transient states forever and the probability that the system goes into absorbing states

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, markov-chains

[image]

I am trying to justify the last statement, but I have failed to do it.

If $\sum \epsilon_k < \infty$, then $\epsilon_k \to 0$. Let $a_j = 1-\epsilon_j$. Then, this implies that for $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $N$ such that for $j > N, |a_j - 1| < \varepsilon$. I don't know how to finish from here.

For the opposite direction, suppose that $\lambda_j > 0$. We have that
$$\lambda_j = (1- \sum_{k=j}^\infty \epsilon_k + \cdots).$$
If the sum diverges, $\lambda_j < 0$, which is a contradiction. Does it sound okay?

Comment: In general, if $p_i$ is a sequence of numbers in $(0,1)$ then $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (1-p_i)>0$ if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i<\infty$. This can be proven by using logarithms to change the infinite product into an infinite sum.

Comment: @Math1000 Thanks for your answer. I found that $\lambda_j = e^{\sum_{k=j}^\infty \log(1-\epsilon_k)} \le e^{-\sum_{k=j}^\infty  \epsilon_k} <1$. But, what I need is the lower bound. How can I find the lower bound using logarithms?